# C++: std::vector<std::vector<T>> comes back as a vector of empty vectors when passed into a fill function by reference

Tags: c++, stdvector

Stripped down to a minimal reproducible example, the code I'm having the issue with is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void fill_vector_of_vectors(vector<vector<char>>& data) // I gave up on trying to think up a proper name for this
{
    data.clear();
    data.resize(4);
    for (vector<char> subarray : data)
    {
        subarray.resize(4, 'x');
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<char>> data;
    fill_vector_of_vectors(data);
    for (vector<char> subarray : data)
    {
        for (char must_be_x: subarray)
        {
            cout << must_be_x;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output is

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

But the actual output of the code is four blank lines. With the debugger, I found out that the filler function does fill out the child vectors properly, but the child vectors in `main()` are empty. Where am I losing the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the changes to the child vectors made in the filler function did not reflect in the context outside of it was the misuse of the iterating `for` statement. In this line,

```
for (vector<char> subarray : data)
```

`subarray` is actually the copy of the child vector of the vector the reference whichof has been passed to the function, so the changes I made to it naturally didn't reflect in the actual child vector. Changing this line to

```
for (vector<char>& subarray : data)
```

Fixed the issue.

Comment: Well, at least this proves that the question was overloaded with unnecessary information and that it did not constitute a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Enlico thank you for pointing out the issues; I applied the necessary edits.

Comment: or better: `for (auto& subarray : data)`

Comment: @Enlico you can use "\[mcve]" to get this: [mcve].

Comment: @MarekR, thank you very much! I should just stick the acronym in my mind.

Comment: @Enlico given that OP didnt know what was the issue, I don't think the mre could have been any more minimal. Of course they could have tried harder before asking the question, but then we wouldnt have the question in the first place ;).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, my point is exactly this. Trying to produce a minimal example is generally enough to ask a good question, or to reject the idea of asking the question because it turns out to be trivial (or, if it's not that trivial, one can post a good question and relative answer at the same time).

Comment: @Enlico my point  is that there are lots of bad questions about this issue, compared to them this is a well written one ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, it is _now_, not when I wrote my first comment.

Comment: @Enlico oh now I see what you mean :) Sorry for interfering.

Comment: @MarekR I wanted to be precise in my answer without suggesting the indiscriminate use of `auto` in such situations. It is, however, a very convenient tool to improve code readability.